# importing a font into css file to work with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

After purchasing a font to use in a web site I am working on, I can't get the font to work in MS Internet Explorer. It works in FF and Chrome. I have the font in the same directory as the .css file.

In my .css file I have:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'stnzq'; /*a name to be used later*/
   src: url('gill-sans-mt-597cad0a854c6.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

and I them use the following:

```
.clientname-text {
   font-family: stnzq;
   font-size: 2.3vw;
   color: #A7C1E3;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Can anyone see why this not work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `.ttf` files aren't compatible with IE.  I think you need a font with `.eot` format. Try adding `src: url('gill-sans-mt-597cad0a854c6.eot')` which should work for IE9+ at least.

Comment: TTF does work in IE 9+, but the font has to be 'installable' for it to work, and a web font by default is probably not (installable is likely a more expensive licence). That means you may have to change the ttf or convert it to another format like eot. See duplicate question or [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf).

Comment: RESOLVED. My question related to Internet Explorer which my code did not work. However, it does work in Edge, Edge is the browser which will be used on this project. This is for company internal viewing so I can restrict it to which ever browser it works on.